# CKeditor form problem adding post to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ckeditor

Im currently trying to use CKeditor to have a custom form on a website. Problem when I want to add the textarea to the database is that the form adds extra code.

```
query=>INSERT INTO post(title,author,post) VALUES ('Jomoja','Djenci','
testpost

\r\n')
```

the post "testpost" was  just to test. It adds automatically 2 lines and yet \r\n') when I do a

```
$postt=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["postt"]);
```

Without the CKeditor I have no problem adding the post to the database...

How can I remove those 2 lines and \r\n?

Comment: What about HTML and accented characters? Is it saving these also in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure !! 
you can try this

```
 $postt = str_ireplace(array("\r","\n",'\r','\n'),'', $postt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too impatient. :-) Looked around a bit and I downloaded the auto save plugin from CKeditor and now it saves to database without any error.

Thanks for the help guys!